# Postgres-XL does not insert rows

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xc

I have successfully installed and started postgres-xl on localhost(Ubuntu 14.04).
(Two datanodes, 1 coord) 
The problem is: 0 rows after insert

```
CREATE TABLE test1 ( id bigint NOT NULL, profile bigint NOT NULL,   status integer NOT NULL, switch_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT test1_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) ) to node (datanode1, datanode2);

 insert into test1 (id, profile, status, switch_date) select a, round(random()*10000), round(random()*4), now() - '1 year'::interval * round(random() * 40) from generate_series(1,10) a;
INSERT 0 0

select * from test1;
 id | profile | status | switch_date 
----+---------+--------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

And finally

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('test1'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 0 bytes
(1 row)
```

I followed the [instructions](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/install-short.html) (with my parameters) but there was error
on creating database, and to fix it I run commands on my nodes:

```
  $ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -p 15432 -c "CREATE NODE coord1 WITH (TYPE = 'coordinator', PORT = 35432)" postgres
  $ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -p 25432 -c "CREATE NODE coord1 WITH (TYPE = 'coordinator', PORT = 35432)" postgres
  $ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -p 15432 -c "select pgxc_pool_reload()" postgres
  $ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -p 25432 -c "select pgxc_pool_reload()" postgres
```

And on coord:

```
SELECT pgxc_pool_reload()
```

After I created database, tables and DDL-commands(create table, alter table) were executed successfully,I see changes (all nodes)  but now I got problems with inserting, because no errors occures but tables empty!

My configs:

```
~$  find /usr/local/pgsql -name *.conf -print -exec grep "5432\|666" {} \;
/usr/local/pgsql/data_coord1/pg_hba.conf
/usr/local/pgsql/data_coord1/pg_ident.conf
/usr/local/pgsql/data_coord1/postgresql.conf
port = 35432                # (change requires restart)
pooler_port = 36667         # Pool Manager TCP port
gtm_port = 6666         # Port of GTM
/usr/local/pgsql/data_gtm/gtm.conf
port = 6666             # Port number of this GTM.
/usr/local/pgsql/data_datanode1/pg_hba.conf
/usr/local/pgsql/data_datanode1/pg_ident.conf
/usr/local/pgsql/data_datanode1/postgresql.conf
port = 15432                # (change requires restart)
pooler_port = 16667         # Pool Manager TCP port
gtm_port = 6666         # Port of GTM
/usr/local/pgsql/data_datanode2/pg_hba.conf
/usr/local/pgsql/data_datanode2/pg_ident.conf
/usr/local/pgsql/data_datanode2/postgresql.conf
port = 25432                # (change requires restart)
pooler_port = 26667         # Pool Manager TCP port
gtm_port = 6666         # Port of GTM
```

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. no matter what kind of distribution - allways empty

```
) distribute by REPLICATION; ...)  distribute by HASH(id); ....) distribute by MODULO(status);
```

or default `create table t1(id serial, k integer);`

all off them empty after insert, insert always returns

```
INSERT 0 0
```

Comment: Does a simple `insert into test1 (id, profile, status, switch_date) values (...)` work?

Comment: no, it does not - insert into t1(k) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
INSERT 0 0
t=# select * from t1;
 id | k 
----+---
(0 rows)

Comment: I found http://sourceforge.net/p/postgres-xl/tickets/18/ and looks like it is still does not work